# Rust Ink - Execution finished with debug buffer

Tags: ink, flipper

I have working `substrate-contracts-node` and `contracts-ui` and I want to deploy a `flipper` smart contract. When I try to deploy flipper smart contract I got:

```
DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: panicked at 'dispatching ink! constructor failed: could not read input', /home/tomek/workspaces/flipper/lib.rs:8:5
```

I did not change flipper source code at all, what I do wrongly? My goal is to have fully working development environment for ink smart contracts.

[image]

Comment: Please post all the versions of the involved components (`cargo contract` + `substrate-contracts-node`) and and a repo with the "flipper" you are trying to compile.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/flipper/lib.rs) the contract you're trying to deploy?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. I worked through this tutorial a few weeks ago and it worked fine, but re-doing it today gives me the `tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: panicked at 'dispatching ink! constructor failed: could not read input', /home/bosr/rust/flipper/lib.rs:8:5` Here are the first 15 lines of the lib.rs file: ```#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)] use ink_lang as ink; #[ink::contract]
pub mod flipper { /// Defines the storage of your contract. /// Add new fields to the below struct in order /// to add new static storage fiel

Comment: I am also getting same error. Can anyone please help? I would also reward with a bounty if someone resolves the issue. ```
Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `MultiAddress`, variant doesn't exist', runtime/src/lib.rs:410 This is a bug. Please report it at: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/issues/new 2022-12-23 09:54:15.467 WARN tokio-runtime-worker wasm-runtime: Evicting failed runtime instance error=Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `MultiAddress`,

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the latest releases of [`substrace-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases/tag/v0.24.0), [`cargo-contract`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-contract/2.0.2) and [ink!](https://crates.io/crates/ink/4.0.1)

We also have official repo with examples: https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples